# Opinions on DoFactory framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net, design-patterns, user-interface, frameworks

[Dofactory](http://dofactory.com) has a 3.5 framework for developing software and includes some design patterns which are explained in a document. There's a sample app built using the framework which has user interfaces for WinForm, WPF, ASP.NET (WebForms), ASP.NET MVC, plus DAL's using Linq & ADO.NET which makes it a candidate for a learning tool and a framework to be used in real world apps.

I am not sure about the quality and ease of use of the framework. I would like to hear opinions from people who actually used it and from ones who hear stories about it.

I am also interested in similar good frameworks which include a DAL and business layers (beside CSLA).

Comment: I can't comment on the usability of the DoFactory stuff. I just wanted to say: I'm confused about how they put design patterns into a framework. I mean, the whole concept of design patterns is that they apply to different situations, not as a hard-and-fast solution. To quote the originator of the term, "Each pattern describes a problem that occurs over and over again in our environment, and then describes the core of the solution to that problem, in such a way that you can use this solution a million times over, without ever doing it the same way twice."

Comment: Every framework has some patterns. .NET, a framework, has several. It just means you're using a pattern to do a specific thing. Like the factory pattern for data access where the developer doesn't care which database type is being used and uses it over and over.

Comment: Dofactory is a terrible resource for design patterns. I would avoid them if you can.

Comment: @Ty, why is it a bad source? a small sample on a pattern, its good enough to see how the pattern works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used DoFactory 2.0, I really like the documentation which came with it. especially where it showed where design pattern were used in the .Net framework.

the framework was good, in the sense that i was able to get to grips with what goes where. I liked how it included some of the PEAA patterns. I would be very interested how the MVC and WPF clients have been implemented.

before you buy this have a look at [S#arp Architecture](http://sharp-architecture.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

which has a full pledged orm, IoC, MVC, WCF, Domain Driven, Unit Testing, Validation, each of these tools are based on patterns... also look around the site, its has good documentation

Comment: As of 03/06/2015 the link to S#arp Architecture is dead.  See [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sharp-architecture/YJiCmIGgpaY](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sharp-architecture/YJiCmIGgpaY).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a compilation of already existing documentation. There already are some excellent books about design patterns and .Net. 
In addition to that, they use "LINQ-TO-SQL" for their DAL, which is [already dead](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx).
It looks like their framework is not up to date anymore...

Comment: The design patterns books explain the patterns. The DoFactory framework is a real usable framework which uses known design patterns. So the books and the framework are not the same thing.

Linq-To-SQL as a way to access SQL Server is not dead. It's can't because it's in the CLR and it's part of the language.

L2S as an ORM might not be supported anymore by MS but it's very similar to Entity Framework, the knowledge is still useful.

Too many people get confused between the ORM and the language part.

Answer (score 0):

We used DoFactory for .NET 2.0 and liked it.